# Powershell command to find list of users allowed to log onto computer

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to find a way of using powershell to list the users assigned logon rights to a computer. But I'm unable to find the syntax if its even possible. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking to find this data strictly from AD or do you want to see what groups have logon rights based on a computer's local security policy?

Comment: Strictly from AD

Comment: The attribute you are looking to query on an `ADUser` object is `userWorkstations`.

Comment: If i use the following code it doesn't report an error but doesn't give a result either. `Get-ADUser -Filter  {userworkstations -eq "CZC921BR8T"}`

Comment: Are you sure that user has "CZC921BR8T" listed as a Workstation in the user's property ?

Comment: It should also be noted that if the user does not have the `userWorkstations` attribute set, that means they have no restrictions and can also login to that computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to query for `ADUser` objects that have their workstation logon explicitly restricted, you can query for values in the `userWorkstations` attribute. Since that attribute is a string with comma-separated values, you will need to potentially manipulate that data properly before doing a compare.

```
$computer = 'computername'
Get-ADUser -Filter "userWorkstations -like '*$computer*'" -Properties userWorkstations |
    Where-Object { ($_.userWorkstations -split ',') -contains $computer }
```

You are not bound to this solution because there are a few ways to retrieve the data you want. I chose to use `-split ','` because that will create an array where the `-contains` operator can find an exact match.

Using the `-like` operator in the `-Filter` allows for wildcard (`*`) matching. `-eq` is only going to work if the particular workstation is the only one listed in the `userWorkstations` attribute. You could potentially forego `-like` all together and get the same result. It is something worth testing since performance could be different<sup>[1]</sup>.

`Where-Object` here provides exact matching. Since the AD `-Filter` parameter does not support containment operators, you have to rely on `-like` with wildcards for delimited strings. Since `-like 'system1*'` would also match `system12334`, we need to ensure that we only return our desired exact match.

---

**Note:** If your local security policy on your computer allows Domain Users to log on locally or interactively, then having no `userWorkstations` attribute value on a user means that user can log on to that machine. So to get a complete picture, you need to examine the local security policy of the machine and determine which domain users that actually applies to.

---

<sup>[1] My personal, limited testing showed using the `-Filter` with the `-like` operator cut my query time by 59%.</sup>

Comment: Just to be clear, the reason for the subsequent `Where-Object` is because if you have a computer called CZC921BR8T**A**, that will satisfy the `-like` comparison, but it does not mean the user can log into CZC921BR8T. So you have to split by the commas and look for *exact* matches after.

Comment: Yes. That is correct. If the AD filter supported containment operators, it would be overkill/redundant.